# free unity3d-like game engine with graphical viewing tool

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unreal-development-kit

I am currently developing games for my company in Unity3d for iOS. I would like to start making games for myself but the initial investment for unity3d or unreal engine is way to high for me(for unity i would have to pay 1500$ for the engine itself and another 1500$ just for the iOS porting system). I like unity3d very much because it is way easier to organize your world, from lights and environment placement to physics, shaders, and mapping.

Is there a game engine with an editing graphical tool out there that requires no taxes for publishing your games? The game engine would also have to be able to port to iOS and/or W8; also i am interested in game engines that have substatial support both from the community and from the development team.

i got my eyes set on Irrlicht Engine but i don't think it has a graphical environment tool.

Comment: The minimum payment is only 500$? You can use Unity Free and the iOS upgrade costs 500$. 1500$ + 1500$ is only if you buy the "Pro" Versions. But you can start with the free version and sell your game. If you get enough money you can buy the Pro Version afterwards.

Comment: @SidBurn i think that's what i'm going to do.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Torque but in your case it might be worth to look at: [Torque 3D](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-3d)

Another one is [Bork3D](http://bork3d.com/index.php) but a look at their web site makes me thinking that they stop their business.

In general I would recommend to first think about your business plans, then make a pros/cons listing and finally decide what to use. What I mean is: If you think you have some good ideas and talking to other people reveals that they agree with you, you should seriously take into consideration, whether it is worth to invest some money your tools. If you dream of being an independent developer and earn enough money to live comfortably, this should be your goal to reach. And if on the other hand you're experienced Unity dev, so it might save you 100s of hours and lessen the project risks when you are taking what is proved.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up regarding Torque 3D. Heard about it, but forgot. Unfortunately, it only supports 2d on the iOS(paid license, but cheap--150$) and no windows 8 support either, for 2d i would actually prefer cocos2d because i'm familiar with it.

Comment: i will consider investing in unity if nothing comes up, but the investment could well pass 6000$+

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru If I were you I would focus on one platform, publish and then see if it's worth to extend to others. So you can start with the free version and one non-pro plugin for 300€.